# Azure KeyVault - Sign JWT Token

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I began using Azure Keyvault to store private keys for my application.

I have a use case where I need to sign a JWT token with an RSA private key.

When I had the private key in my application memory, it was easy,
I would just do that

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer,
                ...,
                claims,
                ...,
                ...,
                signingCredentials_PrivateKey);
```

Now that I began to use Azure Keyvault, I want to see if it's possible to sign JWT tokens via the `KeyVaultClient.SignAsync` method.

Something along the lines of

```
KeyVaultClient client = ...;
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer,
                ...,
                claims,
                ...,
                ...);
var tokenString = client.SignAsync(myKeyIdentifier, token);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, a JWT token consists of three parts: Header, Payload and Signature. All of them are Base64UrlEncoded.

You can get the signature as following:

```
HMAC-SHA256(
 base64urlEncoding(header) + '.' + base64urlEncoding(payload),
 secret
)
```

So, you need to generate the header and payload, combine them by dot, compute the hash, and then you can get the signature.

Here is a sample for your reference:

```
var byteData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(base64urlEncoding(header) + "." + base64urlEncoding(payload));
var hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
var digest = hasher.ComputeHash(byteData);
var signature = await keyClient.SignAsync(keyIdentifier, "RS256", digest);
var token = base64urlEncoding(header) + "." + base64urlEncoding(payload) + "." + base64urlEncoding(signature)
```

The official SDK documentation for [SignAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.keyvault.keyvaultclientextensions.signasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_KeyVaultClientExtensions_SignAsync_Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault_IKeyVaultClient_System_String_System_String_System_Byte___System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Wiki for [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)

Comment: I found another solution but ended up using yours. See my answer.

Comment: @user10962730 I tested at my side, and got a success. See my new answer.

Answer (score 13):

I ended up using Jack Jia's answer

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer,
                appId,
                claims,
                signDate,
                expiryDate);

var header = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { JwtHeaderParameterNames.Alg, "RS256" },
    { JwtHeaderParameterNames.Kid, "https://myvault.vault.azure.net/keys/mykey/keyid" },
    { JwtHeaderParameterNames.Typ, "JWT" }
}));
var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header + "." + token.EncodedPayload);
var hasher = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
var digest = hasher.ComputeHash(byteData);
var signature = await _keyVault.SignAsync("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/keys/mykey/keyid", "RS256", digest);

return $"{header}.{token.EncodedPayload}.{Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature.Result)}";
```

I found another solution, which I didn't like as much but it "integrates" better with the JWT libraries.

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer,
    appId,
    claims,
    signDate,
    expiryDate,
    new SigningCredentials(new KeyVaultSecurityKey("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/keys/mykey/keyid", new KeyVaultSecurityKey.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback)), "RS256")
    {
        CryptoProviderFactory = new CryptoProviderFactory() { CustomCryptoProvider = new KeyVaultCryptoProvider() }
    });

var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
return handler.WriteToken(token);
```

Turns out that there is a library `Microsoft.IdentityModel.KeyVaultExtensions` with extensions to `SecurityToken` and `ICryptoProvider` which support KeyVault.

My problems with it are

1. I can't reuse an existing instance of `KeyVaultClient` with this solution.
2. It's blocking (Behind the scenes, it calls `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` on `KeyVaultClient.SignAsync`

Comment: I tested your solution. It is perfect.

Comment: @JackJia  I'm curious if you have looked into the rate-limiting factor that Tore Nestenius mentioned in his answer?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone need's offline verification. I used user10962730's answer to generate the token and the following for verifying it offline:

While online, our client will retrieve the public information from our API. RSA Modulus and Exponent will be transfered Base64Url encoded instead of a byte array

```
var keyBundle = await _keyVault.GetKeyAsync("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/keys/mykey/keyid");
return new { n = keyBundle.N, e = keyBundle.E };
```

Then when the client needs to verify a token

```
string jwtToken = "[Header].[Payload].[Signature]";
var jwtParts = jwtToken.Split(".");
var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var p = new RSAParameters() { Modulus = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(key.n), Exponent = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(key.e) };
rsa.ImportParameters(p);
var dataToHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{jwtParts[0]}.{jwtParts[1]}");
byte[] digestBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(dataToHash);
var sigBytes = Base64UrlEncoder.DecodeBytes(jwtParts[2]);
var isVerified = rsa.VerifyHash(digestBytes, "Sha256", sigBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do be aware that if you let Azure Key Vault sign your tokens, then there's a rate-limiting factor that you need to be aware of. I think its better to download the private key from AKV and then sign my tokens locally.

Read more at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/overview-throttling)

Comment: That's a great point, but "better" depends on several factors. If the goal is to keep the private key secret, then the better approach might be to throttle your own clients in response to 429 responses from Key Vault. You could also try using a circuit breaker or high-water-mark pattern to implement some back-pressure where you send your own 429 responses before making an actual request to Key Vault if there have been any recent 429 responses from Key Vault.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a less permissive approach (that is to say, not using KeyVaultClient, and using the new Azure APIs):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.cryptographyclient?view=azure-dotnet will allow you to call a method "SignDataAsync" that accepts the SignatureAlgorithm and your data (in byte[] or Stream form) and a cancellation token. It returns a SignatureResult which can be used to retrieve the actual signature as byte[] and various other information.

SignDataAsync would here be called on the "."-concatenated base64url-encoded header and payload (as described in rfc7515).